# UWP Radial Gauge maximum property causing exception

Tags: xaml, uwp, controls

I have an UWP application that recieves data over MQTT from my ESP32 and displays on the screen. I have one radial gauge that was working nicely but now it's throwing a weird exception about the "Maximum" property.

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException
  HResult=0x802B000A
  Message=The text associated with this error code could not be found.

Failed to assign to property 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.RangeBase.Value'. [Line: 66 Position: 98]
  Source=Windows
  StackTrace:
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator, ComponentResourceLocation componentResourceLocation)
   at UWP.Dcem.InitializeComponent() in C:\Users\ale_5\source\repos\UWP\UWP\UWP\obj\x86\Debug\Dcem.g.i.cs:line 59
   at UWP.Dcem..ctor() in C:\Users\ale_5\source\repos\UWP\UWP\UWP\Dcem.xaml.cs:line 33
```

Without setting that property the gauge appears and doesn't throw any exception, but it's useless as it starts from 0 and ends at 0.

This is the code I'm currently using to render the gauge

```
<controls:RadialGauge Margin="0 65 0 10" x:Name="RadialGaugeControl" Value="0" Minimum="0" 
Maximum="3300" TickSpacing="330" ScaleWidth="20" Unit="mV" TickBrush="Gainsboro" 
ScaleTickBrush="AliceBlue" TrailBrush="#4c79a1" NeedleWidth="5" TickLength="18" Width="300"/>
```

The exception is thrown even when using the Microsoft's example from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/radialgauge)

```
<controls:RadialGauge x:Name="RadialGaugeControl" Column="1" Value="70" Minimum="0" 
    Maximum="180" TickSpacing="20" ScaleWidth="26" Unit="Units" TickBrush="Gainsboro"
    ScaleTickBrush="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    NeedleWidth="5" TickLength="18">
</controls:RadialGauge>
```

Control reference

```
xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
```

Version 6.0.0

Does anyone know whats causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your rendering code and it worked. And from the error message, it should be that you assigned the wrong value type to `Value` (for example, a non-double value such as a string is assigned to Value), independent of the `Maximum` proeprty.

There are some omissions in the official example, `RadialGauge` does not contain the `Column` property, please remove this property, or change to `Grid.Column="1"`, it can run normally.

We will report the problem with this document to modify it as soon as possible to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: I'm not understanding the mistake here, I'm not using a grid either the column property. I'm having a weird issue with the maximum value, check it out [link](https://i.imgur.com/G1viRge.png)  Do you have any ideia? I've already tryied resintalling the controls package, it didn't work =/

Comment: In your screenshot, I noticed that two `Maximum` appeared. Have you repeatedly set this property?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The error line is the radial gauge, then a comment and then a slider

Comment: Sorry, your question cannot be reproduced at this time. Can you provide the minimum/target system version of your application? You can also try to create a new blank project and introduce the control to see if there will be the same problem

Comment: Yea, it seems it was a weird bug with VS. Creating a new project worked fine